# Downloading Map tiles from Mapbox or OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I am trying an offline Map application in which I need to show a map up to some zooming level.

I thought that I would download tiles and put it locally.

How can Map tiles can be downloaded from Mapbox or OpenStreetMap?

Comment: There are already [various similar questions on the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=openstreetmap+offline+tiles).

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [Sas Planet](http://sasgis.ru/sasplaneta/)
You can define your own TMS and XYZ layers to be scrapped